# Is there a function in Python to find the type of variable?

Tags: javascript, python

Does Python have the function like JavaScript?

```
typeof variable
```

Comment: check `type()` ...

Comment: Yes its `type`. To check you can use it like `type([]) is list`

Answer (score 0):

Try `type()`

```
>>> number = 1
>>> type(number)
<class 'int'>
>>> text = "Hello"
>>> type(text)
<class 'str'>
>>> arr = [1,2,3]
>>> type(arr)
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply type

type(var)

or if you want to display it too, then use this:

print(type(var))